# TypeError: Unable to get property 'setPromocodeDetails' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have defined my service as

```
angular.module('myservice', []).service('dataService', function() {
  var promocodeDetails = {
    "havePromocode": false,
    "promocode": "",
    "OfferHeading": "",
    "OfferDescription": "",
    "OfferDisclaimer": ""
  };
  return {
    setPromocodeDetails: function(promocode) {
      promocodeDetails = promocode;
    },
    getPromocodeDetails: function() {
      return promocodeDetails;
    }
  };
});
```

I have written jasmine test for it

```
describe('Testing dataservice - a service', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myservice');
  });
  var dataService;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_dataService_) {
    dataService = _dataService_;
  }));
  it('should set the promocodedetail', function() {
    var promocode = {
      'promocode':'12345'
    }
    dataService.setPromocodeDetails(promocode);
    expect(dataService.getPromocodeDetails().promocode).toEqual('12345');
  });
});
```

When I try to run this test, I get the following error

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'setPromocodeDetails' of undefined or null reference
```

Please suggest as I am stuck with this simple test...

Comment: try to change beforeEach(function(){
        module('myservice');
}); to beforeEach(module('myservice')) per any chance ?

Comment: Thanks its working now...But what difference it makes if i use beforeEach(function(){ module('myservice'); }); as i saw this syntax somewhere on internet...

Comment: I guess everything writen on the internet isn't right.  module('myservice') is a generator returning the method initializing the module. By not executing it's return, it's useless